# How do I link the OpenAL library to eclipse in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, filesystem, eclipse, c++

I just downloaded the OpenAL library using the command `sudo apt-get install libopenal1 libopenal-dev`, now I can't find where the library is on my system and how should it be linked with Eclipse. I am new to Ubuntu hence I am not familiar with how Ubuntu's file system works.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the libopenal-dev package installs its headers to /usr/include/AL/ so (since /usr/include is a standard search path) provided you include them as `<AL/whatever.h>` you should not need to do anything else.

Similarly, the library goes in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ (or its 32-bit equivalent) so it should just be a matter of adding `openal` to the list of libraries in your project settings.

FYI since the package appears to provide a .pc file, you can always run `pkg-config --cflags --libs` on the command line and copy the relevant flags and settings from there.

Comment: I tried running a short program, but none of the functions seemed to be defined. It didn't have any trouble finding the header file, but no function works. Header files included: `#include <AL/al.h>    // OpenAL header files
#include <AL/alc.h>`, but even functions like `alcOpenDevice(NULL)` aren't working!

Comment: Tried running, or tried building? Did you add the AL library in the project's C/C++ build settings?

Comment: So obviously, the library is not linked. If it was Windows, we just have to track down the location of .lib files, but in this case, how should I link it? and where will I find the library files and what extension are they stored with?

Comment: Yes I tried building. It just keeps saying that the functions were undefined.

Comment: What you seem to be asking is really an eclipse question, not an Ubuntu question: IIRC you go to Properties --> Settings --> GCC C Linker --> Libraries and add the name of the library (minus its 'lib' prefix) in the top pane e.g. for libopenal you would add 'openal'. You *may* need to add the library path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ in the bottom pane but try it without first (since that should be a built-in search path for gcc/g++)